# Using PowerShell Code to Access _vti_bin/lists.asmx

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, powershell, powershell-2.0

Does anyone any example code on how to go about using PowerShell to manipulate the SharePoint list using Web Proxy Services, I saw that the following operations are supported.

If Someone could provide example code for each of the below item it would be great.

```
o   AddAttachment

o   AddDiscussionBoardItem

o   AddList

o   AddListFromFeature

o   ApplyContentTypeToList

o   CheckInFile

o   CheckOutFile

o   CreateContentType

o   DeleteAttachment

o   DeleteContentType

o   DeleteContentTypeXmlDocument

o   DeleteList

o   GetAttachmentCollection

o   GetList

o   GetListAndView

o   GetListCollection

o   GetListContentType

o   GetListContentTypes

o   GetListItemChanges

o   GetListItemChangesSinceToken

o   GetListItems

o   GetVersionCollection

o   UndoCheckOut

o   UpdateContentType

o   UpdateContentTypeXmlDocument

o   UpdateContentTypesXmlDocument

o   UpdateList

o   UpdateListItems
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2010/06/24/using-new-webserviceproxy-to-get-modify-and-add-items-to-a-list-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank RoManiac, i guess some one also answers and provides examples for other commands also